# How can I select a column by name in jooq, when result record has two columns of different tables with the same name?

Tags: java, jooq

I am using Jooq and as a result of a query with some joins I have a list of [Record](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html) .

This record includes two columns with name "id" and I would need to select one of them.

This [method](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#get(java.lang.String)) has String as parameter and it is not failing when passing "id" (probably returning the first occurrence).

The other alternative I saw is to use the [method](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#get(int)) that receives an int with the index. This would work ok but I would prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative I found on this case is to use the [method](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#get(org.jooq.Field)) that receives [Field](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html) as parameter.
By using Field we can specify the table and column name so we are sure that we are selecting the column that we want.

So basically if we have table A and B both with "id" columns on the result of the query we can just define a field

```
final Field<UUID> bId = tableB.ID;
```

And then when processing the results we can access it by

```
query.fetch().forEach(r -> { UUID theId = r.get(bId); });
```